# Is it necessary to wash our feet after Navagraha Pradakshina?

Tags: belief, temple, navagraha

There is a  belief among some people that we have to wash our feet or take bath after visiting Saneeswara Temple or circumambulating Navagraha idols. I read that one should wash their feet after visiting Saneeswara Temple or circumambulating Navagraha idols.

Is it really necessary to wash feet after Navagraha Pradakshina?

Answer (score 5):

[Brahmasri Vaddiparti Padmakar](http://pedia.desibantu.com/vaddiparti-padmakar/) says there's no sastra which compels us to wash our feet after *Navagraha Pradikshana*. But if we anoint Shani Deva idol with oil (*Tailabhishekam*) and if only Pandit or priest of temple instructs us to wash feet after *Tailabhishekam*, then we need to wash our feet. He says that people don't wash their feet after anointing Shani Deva in Shani Shingnapur.

Here is his [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1k4NGAK6N4) in Telugu.